# IIS 502.5 error in Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am using Sitecore XP 9.1.1 and xCommerce 9.1. I have published code to the root but on few pages I am getting below error -

[image]

In postman, I am able to access token but on bootstrapping, I am getting error-

An error occurred while starting the application.

[image]

Exception in log file -

12492 17:23:59 ERROR Query Exception - Query:https://commerceauthoring.projectname-sc911xc91xp0.dev.local/api/Carts('Defaultbcc4d56b-54ce-469f-b2d1-3f78124bc6a8AUS2')?$expand=Lines($expand=CartLineComponents,CartSubLineComponents($expand=CartLineComponents)),Components - Message:An error occurred while processing this request.
12492 17:23:59 ERROR Failed to render rendering
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.ExecuteController(Controller controller)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

Nested Exception

Exception: Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException
Message: An error occurred while processing this request.
Source: Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy
   at Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy.Proxy.GetValue[T](DataServiceQuerySingle`1 query)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Pipelines.Carts.CartProcessor.GetCart(String userId, String shopName, String cartId, String customerId, String currency)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Pipelines.Carts.LoadCart.Process(ServicePipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Services.ServiceProvider.RunPipeline[TRequest,TResult](String pipelineName, TRequest request)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Connect.Managers.CartManager.LoadCart(IVisitorContext visitorContext, String shopName, String cartName, String customerId, Boolean recalculateTotals, StringPropertyCollection propertyBag)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Connect.Managers.CartManager.GetCurrentCart(IVisitorContext visitorContext, IStorefrontContext storefrontContext, Boolean recalculateTotals, StringPropertyCollection propertyBag)
   at projectname.Feature.Store.Repositories.Store.StoreRepository.GetPreferredStore(IStorefrontContext storefrontContext, IVisitorContext visitorContext, IContext context) in C:\Projects\Azure-CI\src\Feature\Store\code\Repositories\Store\StoreRepository.cs:line 93
   at projectname.Feature.Store.Controllers.SelectedStoreController.GetModel() in C:\Projects\Azure-CI\src\Feature\Store\code\Controllers\SelectedStoreController.cs:line 38
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc.Controllers.StandardController.Index()
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

Nested Exception

Exception: Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException
Message:                                      IIS 502.5 Error

#### HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Common causes of this issue:

- The application process failed to start
- The application process started but then stopped
- The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port

Troubleshooting steps:

- Check the system event log for error messages
- Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
- Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect

For more information visit:                [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808681](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=808681)                                  
Source: Microsoft.OData.Client
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)

**Sitecore Commerce Engine Service Logs (Updated)**

00020 12:34:00 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.EntityNotFound: Text=Core.block.LoadEnvironment.EnvironmentCouldNotBeFound: Environment=ProjectNameAuthoring
00020 12:34:00 ERROR PipelineAbort:Core.block.LoadEnvironment.EnvironmentCouldNotBeFound: Environment=ProjectNameAuthoring
00001 12:34:00 INFO Application startup exception
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Builder.ODataModelBuilder' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.Library.EdmConstants' from assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Edm, Version=7.5.0.20627, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Builder.ODataModelBuilder..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Builder.ODataModelBuilder..ctor()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder..ctor()
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__4()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IConfigureServiceApiPipeline configureServiceApiPipeline, IStartNodePipeline startNodePipeline, IConfigureOpsServiceApiPipeline configureOpsServiceApiPipeline, IStartEnvironmentPipeline startEnvironmentPipeline, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions`1 loggingSettings, IOptions`1 applicationInsightsSettings, IOptions`1 certificatesSettings, IOptions`1 allowedOriginsOptions, GetDatabaseVersionCommand getDatabaseVersionCommand)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Builder.ODataModelBuilder' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.Library.EdmConstants' from assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Edm, Version=7.5.0.20627, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Builder.ODataModelBuilder..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Builder.ODataModelBuilder..ctor()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder..ctor()
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__4()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---

00020 12:34:00 INFO Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://commerceauthoring.ProjectName-sc911xc91xp0.dev.local/commerceops/GetCatalogMappings(environmentName='')
00020 12:34:00 INFO Request finished in 180.5607ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
00067 12:54:54 INFO Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://127.0.0.1:22525/iisintegration  0
00067 12:54:54 INFO Request finished in 0.4942ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8

Snap of browser console after performing steps mentioned by Shabaaz Shaikh - 
[image]

Please let me know how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you check IIS logs?

Comment: Also check logs of your commerce engine service

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal I have edited the question to add instance logs. I do not have read permissions for iis logs.

Comment: @VipinBanka I have edited the question to add instance logs

Comment: @NidhiVaishnava you have added the logs from Sitecore instance, add the logs from Commerce Engine service as well.

Comment: @VipinBanka logs from commerce engine added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Was facing the same error,
"

*HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
Common causes of this issue:
The application process failed to start
The application process started but then stopped
The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect*

"
For me the issue was that my license was expired.
So I had replaced it in the siteroot/appdata and site was up but the commerce section was still not working.

The following are the places that we need to replace the license file.

[image]

**But if the application license is correct**. Then the application (business) is unable to connect to the database.
please check the logs.

**Solution** :

Here is where you need to update the details of your database in the following files
i.e.

1. **Global.json** : 
   *commerce Proj\src\Project\HabitatHome\engine\wwwroot\bootstrap*
2. **Plugin.SQL.PolicySet-1.0.0.json** :
   *commerce Proj\src\Project\HabitatHome\engine\wwwroot\data\Environments*

**or if you have already deployed then :**
in all the copies of the above 2 files located in folders related to commerce
i.e.:

**CommerceAuthoring_suffix

CommerceMinions_suffix

CommerceOps_suffix

CommerceShops_suffix**

[image]

[image]

Comment: First, I checked the licenses. License files at xconnect were invalid. So I changed the licenses. But it didnt work. Then I tried the second option of changing the databases in all 8 config files. Now, when I hit https://projectname.dev.local/sitecore/login, it keeps on loading but the errors in event viewer is gone. Thanks for resolving the error. But do you have any solution for this loading issue?

Comment: can you please post a snap of the console of the browser

Comment: Added in question, please check.

Comment: Don't worry it may take some time initially, you can try resetting IIS and then reload the site. In the mean time you can have your lunch. :)

Comment: It kept loading, so I checked the logs of commerce authoring, it had an exception that I have added in question.

Comment: wait hold on logs for commerce authoring ? are you trying to run the business tools ? did sc cms loaded correctly? also this question is getting cluttered, it would be more convenient if you opened a new query.

Comment: I am not running business tools. CMS didn't load.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your helpful comments and suggestions.The error is resolved now.
I reverted all the changes that I made to the Authoring, Shops, Ops and Minions roles. Build and deployed fresh assemblies and changed the database server names in all 8 config files as suggested in previous answer.
Afer this, I ran the instance again and it threw a different exception of Certificate matching. 
To resolve this, I took help of this blog - 
http://andrewsutherland.azurewebsites.net/2018/07/01/valid-certificate-thumbprint-not-matching-in-sitecore-experience-commerce-9/
And now the page is working again!

Comment: kudos.. ... : )